# Filtering NULL values in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below query:

```
select 
  CASE WHEN rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD = 'SA' THEN ap.APPL_CD + ' ' + rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD
       WHEN ap.APPL_SID = 1 THEN  rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD  
       ELSE NULL
       END as dropdownName,   
  rt.role_type_sid as dropdownID,   
  rt.actv_ind as active,   
  'Application Role' as dropdownCatagory        
 from cdms_role_type rt   
 INNER JOIN CDMS_APPLICATION ap  
 ON rt.APPL_SID = ap.APPL_SID
 where role_type_cd != 'All Role Types'
 **AND (CASE WHEN rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD = 'SA' THEN ap.APPL_CD + ' ' + rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD
       WHEN ap.APPL_SID = 1 THEN  rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD END ) IS NOT NULL**
```

I want to avoid the last AND condition and still want to get rid of NULL values in dropdown column.How do I go for it? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out only the records that would produce a non-null value:

```
select 
  CASE WHEN rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD = 'SA' THEN ap.APPL_CD + ' ' + rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD
       ELSE rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD
       END as dropdownName,   
  rt.role_type_sid as dropdownID,   
  rt.actv_ind as active,   
  'Application Role' as dropdownCatagory        
 from cdms_role_type rt   
 INNER JOIN CDMS_APPLICATION ap  
 ON rt.APPL_SID = ap.APPL_SID
 where role_type_cd != 'All Role Types'
   and (rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD = 'SA' or ap.APPL_SID = 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

A `CASE` that doesn't match any of the `WHEN` clauses is `NULL`, so just use that fact to turn you code into a simple match:

```
...
where role_type_cd != 'All Role Types'
AND (rt.ROLE_TYPE_CD = 'SA' OR ap.APPL_SID = 1)
```

There is no way to avoid the last `AND`, but it's fairly simple - I don't know why you'd want to avoid such a thing.

Note: When using `OR`, make sure you use brackets. Because `AND` takes precedence, without brackets, A AND B OR C is parsed as (A AND B) OR C... not what you want.

fyi, a `CASE` without an `ELSE` clause is equivalent to a `CASE` with an `ELSE NULL`, that's why it's `NULL` when is doesn't match any of the `WHEN` clauses.

Comment: A CASE that doesn't match is null - didn't know that +1